# Prettier и стрелочные функции js

Tags: javascript, функции, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

есть, например, функция:

```
const fn = par => par;
```

после форматирования Prettier`ом он добавляет необязательные круглые скобки параметру, как это исправить?

```
const fn = (par) => par;
```

Comment: Зачем?  *(8 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor а зачем ставить необязательные скобки, если можно обойтись и без них

Comment: очевидно это можно настроить

Comment: @Grundy понятное дело, но какой параметр отвечает за это ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел:

```
"prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
```

Comment: Молодец. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете плагин "Prettier - Code formatter" для VS Code зайдите в параметры(Ctrl+,) в поисковой строке введите "prettier arrow" и установите значение "avoid". Готово[image: введите сюда описание изображения]